# Generic way of getting const-qualification of elements from container

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I need a generic function that can take either a const or non-const reference to a container, and return the corresponding reference to elements qualified as per the container.

Something along these lines:

```
template <typename C>
auto get_nth( C& c, int i ) -> /* not-sure-what, but let's call it T */
{
      //.... some tricky code here ...
}
```

I would like to stress that if C expands to

```
SomeContainer const
```

then T would be

```
SomeContainer::const_reference
```

and otherwise

```
SomeContainer::reference
```

I think I can put it together using type traits and mtl if, my question is if there is a shorter, cleaner way.

I'm using C++x11 (obviously) and boost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you pass an rvalue as the first parameter to `get_nth`, do you want to return an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference to the i-th element?

Comment: @FredOverflow I'm only interested on lvalues. The correct thing is then to use ...(C& c...) in that case, right?

Comment: Yes. Nevertheless, I will update my answer :)

Comment: What's the problem with `*std::next(begin(c), i);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `typename C::reference`, see 23.2.1 [container.requirements.general] §4.

---

Oh wait, the above doesn't work if `C` is already `const`. But wait, `decltype` to the rescue!

```
template <typename C>
auto get_nth( C&& c, int i ) -> decltype(*c.begin())
{
      //.... some tricky code here ...
}
```

If you also want to support C-style arrays which have no `begin` member function:

```
#include <iterator>

template <typename C>
auto get_nth( C&& c, int i ) -> decltype(*std::begin(c))
{
      //.... some tricky code here ...
}
```

And the implementation really isn't *that* tricky:

```
#include <iterator>

template <typename C>
auto get_nth( C&& c, int i ) -> decltype(*std::begin(c))
{
    auto it = std::begin(c);
    std::advance(it, i);
    return *it;
}
```

---

Note that the above solution accepts lvalues and rvalues, but it will always return an lvalue reference. Depending on the client code, this may be a performance concern. Take the following example code:

```
std::string s = get_nth(std::vector<std::string> { "hello", "world" }, 0);
```

This will copy the result into `s`, even though moving it would be perfectly valid (and, of course, faster).

To solve this problem, we need two overloads, one for lvalues and one for rvalues:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename C>
auto get_nth( C& c, int i ) -> decltype(*std::begin(c))
{
    auto it = std::begin(c);
    std::advance(it, i);
    return *it;
}

template <typename C>
auto get_nth( C&& c, int i )
-> typename std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<C&&>::value,
                           decltype(std::move(*std::begin(c)))>::type
{
    auto it = std::begin(c);
    std::advance(it, i);
    return std::move(*it);
}
```

Now the result will be moved into `s`. The `enable_if` part is necessary because due to reference collapsing rules, `C&&` can also bind to lvalues, and then the call to initialize `s` would be ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks! It is not as clean as I would like, but it is a lot better of what I had in mind.

Comment: If only it allowed for ADL of `begin`... :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I knew somebody would find an opportunity for improvement somewhere :)